# How to align radio button to the left of my text?

Tags: html, css

So for my raid buttons, I want them to align to the right of my text, like other elements above, but I cant figure out how.
Here is the fiddle and code I have for my buttons.

```
<label>What kind of Ice Cream you like?</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="choco" id="radio">                     Chocolate</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="vanil" id="radio">Vanilla</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle" name="icecream" value="rocky" id="radio">Rocky Road</label><br>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/russiandobby/gfj1nper/4/

I tried many ways but my radio buttons either end up under the text or messed up order like that.

Comment: three rows with left align

Answer (score 2):

Try using an id for each radio, like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="chocolate">Chocolate</label>
    <input type="radio" name="icecream" value="choco" id="chocolate"> 
</div>
```

*edited

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="icecream" value="choco" id="chocolate">
    <label for="chocolate">Chocolate</label>
    <input type="radio" name="icecream" value="choco" id="vanila">
    <label for="vanila">Vanila</label>
```

the name attribute should have same value rather than the id's having same value

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to mess with the styling more to align everything exactly how you want it, but to get the radio inputs to the right of the text simply put the `<input>` element after the `<label>` element.

At the moment your `<label>` is wrapping the input. Place it wholly before the `<input>` element.

Additionally: for usability and accessibility, clicking the label should trigger your radio input. To enable this set a `for=""` attribute on each label that matches a unique `id=""` attribute for each input.

```
<label for="choco">Chocolate</label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="choco" id="choco">
<label for="vanil">Vanilla</label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="vanil" id="vanil">
<label for="rocky">Rocky Road</label><input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle" name="icecream" value="rocky" id="rocky">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try These Solutions

```css
  
    body{
  background-color:#42f4e2;
}
#title{
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
}
#mainform{
   background-color:#e8ecf2;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  
  
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
   
}

#survey-form{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 95%;
  text-align:center;
}
select{
  display: inline-block;
  height:30px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.redio-wrap label{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

.redio-wrap label:first-child{
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <h1 id="title">Survey Form</h1>
    <div id="mainform">
      <form action="/action_page.php" method="get" id="survey-form">
        <label>*First name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your name"><br>
        <label>*Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"><br>
        <label>*Age:</label> <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter your Age"><br>
        <!--For the Drop Down menu-->
        <label>Describe your mood:</label>
        <select>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                        <option value="happy">Happy</option>
                        <option value="sad">Sad</option>
                        <option value="angry">Angry</option>
                        <option value="neutral">Neutral</option>
        </select><br>
        <!--For the Drop Down menu end-->
        <!--Radio buttons start-->

        <div class="redio-wrap">

        <label>What kind of Ice Cream you like?</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="choco" id="radio"> Chocolate</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="vanil" id="radio">Vanilla</label>
        <label><input type="radio" style="vertical-align: middle" name="icecream" value="rocky" id="radio">Rocky Road</label>

      </div>

      </form>



    </div>
```

Comment: you have a wrap to label with this class .redio-wrap and increased width #survey-form this class 95%

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and upon reviewing I found the following to solve the problem, which I applied to your ice cream variables:

First, in the HTML window, apply the following:

```
<div class="rowTab">
  <div class="labels">
<label for="ice cream Type"> What kind of Ice Cream you like?</label>
  <div/>
   <div class="rightTab">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
         <li class="radio">
       <label>Chocolate<input name="radio-buttons"
value="1" type="radio" class="ice cream Type"></label></li>
         <li class="radio">
       <label>Vanilla<input name="radio-buttons" 
value="2" type="radio" class="ice cream Type"></label></li>
         <li class="radio">
       <label>Rocky Road<input name="radio-buttons"
value="3" type="radio" class="ice cream Type"></label></li>
```

THEN, in the CSS window apply the following:

```
.ice cream type,
input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: right;
  margin-right:??px;
  }
```

In this case, from the HTML window you are defining the class 'ice cream type' for each flavor, then in the CSS window you are styling it with 'float: right;' which should put the radio buttons to the RIGHT of each flavor's name..